# Hash table solution to twoSum

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, k-sum

I try the most to solve a twoSum problem in leetcode

> Given an array of integers, return **indices** of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have **exactly** one solution, and you may not use the *same* element twice.
>
> **Example:**
>
> Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
>
> Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
>   return [0, 1].

The plan:

1. brute force to iterate len(nums)   O(n)
2. search for target - num[i] with a hash table   O(1)

Implement

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        nums_d = {}
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            nums_d.setdefault(nums[i], []).append(i)

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            sub_target = target - nums[i]
            nums_d[nums[i]].pop(0) #remove the fixer
            result = nums_d.get(sub_target)#hash table to search 

            if result: 
                return [i, result[0]]
        return []
```

I strives  hours for this solution but found that answer accepted but not passed Score 60.

> Runtime: 60 ms, faster than 46.66% of Python3 online submissions for Two Sum.
>   Memory Usage: 16.1 MB, less than 5.08% of Python3 online submissions for Two Sum.

I want to refactor the codes  so that to achieve at least faster than 60%.

Could you please provide hints?

Comment: Take care not to misuse the term [refactoring](https://refactoring.com) when you just mean rewriting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### First some stylistic points

- `nums_d.setdefault(nums[i], []).append(i)`

  The `setdefault` is unnecessary here, you can assign a list normally

  ```
  nums_d[nums[i]] = [i]
  ```
- When you need both the `index` and the `element` use enumerate [see PEP279](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/)

  > ```
  > nums_d = {}
  > for i in range(len(nums)):
  >     nums_d.setdefault(nums[i], []).append(i)
  > ```

  ```
  nums_d = {}
  for i, e  in enumerate(nums):
      nums_d[e] = [i]
  ```
- Use comprehension when possible (They use the C style looping and is considered to be faster)

  ```
  nums_d = { e: [i] for i, e  in enumerate(nums) }
  ```

### Hint

You loop over nums twice, but this can be done in one loop! *To make it O(n)*

Whenever you visit a new element in nums ->

Check if it's sum complement is in `nums_d`, else add the `target - element` to the dictionary with the index as value `t - e : i`

> ```
> nums_d = {}
> for i, e in enumerate(nums):
>     if e in nums_d:
>         return [nums_d[e], i]
>     nums_d[target - e] = i
> ```

Comment: Your first bullet point is only true if each number in the array is unique. Otherwise you override instead of append.

Comment: @Graipher True, a `defaultdict` might be more appropriate there.

Comment: \$O(2n) = O(n).\$

Answer (score 0):

> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.

So there's no need to iterate over `num` twice. In fact, you won't even iterate over it for the full range, because you can return when you found the solution.

With the input given, I'd try this:

```
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9

def twoSum(nums, target):
    for i in nums:
        for m in nums[nums.index(i)+1:]:
            if i + m == target:
                return [nums.index(i), nums.index(m)]

print(twoSum(nums, target))
```

Say `i + m` is your target twoSum, you iterate over nums for each i and then look in the rest of num if there's any `m` for which `i + m = target`, and return when found.

**Edit:** This fails if you have duplicate integers in nums that add up to target, and it'll be slower if the solution is two elements near the end of nums.

Also: thank you for mentioning [Leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/), it's new to me. Nice!

Comment: Hey, long time no see! Unfortunately the code you've supplied is worse than the one in the question, as it takes \$O(n^2)\$ time and either \$O(n)\$ or \$O(n^2)\$ memory, depending on the GC. Where in the question it runs in \$O(n)\$ time and space. Yours is however easier to understand.

Comment: Hi, yes, I know, Ludisposed pointed that out as well, hence the edit. I came across the question in Triage, and thought I might as well try an answer. Hadn't thought beyond nums given, with which it yields the answer in 1+3+1=5 iterations. I'm not familiar with O(n^2), but I guess that'd be 16 here?

Comment: Ah, he must have deleted his comments. :( Yes it goes by the worst case, so if 11 and 15 were the targets. It's different from mathematics however, as your function runs in IIRC worst case \$\frac{n^2}{2}\$ iterations. And so it's mostly just a vague guess at performance.